# Windows Host Error on firebase login command in vs code

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am using firebase user authentication for my flutter app,when i run firebase login command it gives me an Windows Host Error on vs code however it runs on cmd prompt on pc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK5zh.png)
I have ran
npm install -g firebase tools
and
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

According to tutorial it should show loggedin as abcd@gmail.com but it give the error.